# Can this laptop position decrease cooling efficiency?

Tags: cooling

I have a Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop, and I would like to know if laying in bed (with a hard surface stand beneath it ofc) in the position shown on the picture be bad for the airflow and the cooling?
There are two fans, one at top left corner and one at top right corner, so the air gets out from the back corners of the laptop. There is also some airflow at the bottom of the laptop beneath the fans.

[image: Position]

Comment: As long as it's a flat, hard surface, it will be equivalent to using it on a table.  This isn't a problem.

Comment: So long as the vents are unobstructed, as they would be sitting on a flat desk, then this should be fine.